# File lost IIS_IUSRS permission after a Tortoise SVN operation

Tags: asp.net, svn, iis, tortoisesvn, file-permissions

I recently switched my development machine from Windows XP to Windows 7 and since that switch, I have a problem with files permissions when I do operations with Tortoise SVN.

Example: 
I Have two ASP.NET website set on my local IIS. `Beta` and `Devlo`. `Beta` is a check out of the branch I'm working on and `Devlo` is a check out of the Trunk.
I made some change on the `Beta` website and Check it in.
Then I made a `merge` to reintegrate the branch in the truck on the `Devlo` website, but I got this error when I test it :

```
Parser Error   
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to 
service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details 
and modify your source file appropriately.  

Parser Error Message: Access to the path 'C:\[...]' is denied.
```

After investigation, I discovered that every file that was modified by the Tortoise SVN `merge` lost theirs file permission (Read, Read & Execute) for the users **IUSE** and **IIS_IUSRS**.

I could manually put them back, but this happen every time I perform an operation of this kind. Is there a way to keep those permissions unchanged by the SVN operation?

---

**Update**
Before the Merge, the file was inheriting is permission from the parent folder (has it's supposed to do.)
[image: Before Merge]

But **not** after the merge :

[image: After Merge]

The original file (in the beta folder) was inheriting is permission from the parent folder.
Why the TortoiseSVN (explicitly?) block permission inheritance?

Comment: Can you do a merge with the command line svn.exe to see if it's really TortoiseSVN and not svn.exe?

Comment: svn.exe? I don't have the command line version Of SVN installed. (And I made a file search for SVN.EXE). Does it really matter?

Comment: It would help to clearly define the problem. TortoiseSVN includes it, but perhaps it's embedded in their binaries, that may explain why you can't find it. You can download the stand-alone client here: http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html#windows

Comment: There was a TortoiseSVN update today and I notified it was an command line was an option when installing. I installed it and made a few tries, but don't have the time to understand how this work. I also have AnkhSVN installed so I tried to merge using it and I got the same problem (the file lost it's permissions).

Comment: I have this issue with the command line svn. Very inconventient. My svn client (TortoiseSVN 1.9.7, Build 27907, r1800392) is from 08/08/2017. I will update it and see if the issue is still there.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had the same issue and fixed it with the help of this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8993163/361831

The answer mentions that updated files are copied to a .svn/tmp directory which is located in the top level of your working copy (as of tortoiseSVN 1.7). This top level dir didn't have the IIS permissions so I guess they weren't inheriting during the copy. So I just set the IIS permissions to that top level dir and set to inherit, and that fixed the issue.

Comment: Tested and working, but there's still a problem when your directory structure *needs* to apply different right to some specific sub folders. Like the Write permission on a upload sub directory or whatever. But, at least, the root of the problem is identified. Thanks!

Comment: When you cannot change the permissions of the .svn folder, because some folders have different permissions. You can [reset permission using script/icacls](http://serverfault.com/questions/475612/replace-permission-entries-on-all-child-objects-using-icacls/601853#601853) also:
`cd D:\websites\your-site`, `svn update`, `icacls "D:\websites\your-site\httpdocs\*" /q /c /t /reset`

Answer (score 4):

When subversion updates a file it first creates a temporary version in .svn/tmp/. It then moves the file into the right location. (This to avoid corruptions)

In 1.6 it did this for every directory by itself, but in 1.7 there is just a .svn in the top level directory of your working copy.

If somehow the filesystem permissions of this .svn directory are restricted, it is possible that the restrictions are copied with the file when it is moved in place. (Subversion doesn't change the permissions itself on Windows)

ANSWER: Locate your .svn directory for that project and fix the permissions with permissions needed by your project.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to set these permissions on the folder that contains the files and then let the files inherit these permissions, instead of explicitly setting the permissions on the files themselves.

TortoiseSVN may delete and create files instead of renaming. When a new file is created this way it will not have the original permissions, but it will inherit permissions from its container.

See also: [Explicit vs. Inherited Permissions](http://www.ntfs.com/ntfs-permissions-explicit.htm)

> Each permission that exists can be assigned one of two ways:
>   explicitly or by inheritance. For this reason, permissions are
>   referred to as explicit permissions and inherited permissions.
>
> - Explicit permissions are permissions that are set by default when the object is created, or by user action.
> - Inherited permissions are permissions that are given to an object because it is a child of a parent object.
>
> Similar to the way rights are managed for groups of users, permissions
>   are best managed for containers of objects. Objects within the
>   container inherit all the access permissions in that container.

See also: [TortoiseSVN - Deleting, Moving and Renaming](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-rename.html)

> Since renames and moves are done as a delete followed by an add...

Comment: See my update, the permissions where set to be inherited from its container.

Comment: "When a new file is created this way it will not have the original permissions, but it will inherit permissions from its container" - the problem stated in the question is precisely that this does not happen.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem on both my Win7 64bit machines. I would check in code on one, go to the other, do a Tortoise SVN Update, and have to reset the permissions on the folder to let the parent folder's permissions propagate downwards.

I finally found this article, tried it, and two weeks later it seems to be holding up.

- Open the Registry Editor (click Start > Run, type regedit, then press ENTER).
- Locate the following registry key:
- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
- With the key selected, on the Edit menu, click Add Value, and then add the following registry value:
- Value name: ForceCopyAclwithFile
- Data type: DWORD
- Value data: 1
- Exit the Registry Editor.

http://kb.globalscape.com/KnowledgebaseArticle10473.aspx

Comment: Did not work for me. And after reading the article, I don't see how it could help.