# How to prevent lost file permissions after switch between branches in svn?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

When I do a switch between the trunk and a branch or vice versa in my svn repository the affected files are loosing some of their file permissions.

For ASP.NET to run property the IUSR account needs permission to read the file. This permissions is usually lost while switching.

How can I control how tortoise handles file permissions?

(I'm using Tortoise SVN with Visual SVN Server on Windows)

Comment: Do you have your working copy on a file server or locally?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8993163/1178189

Comment: Thanks! My top _svn was missing the required permissions so it's probably it.